# salt state.apply returns with non-zero exit code

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to apply state '`nettools.sls`' and I'm receiving

> ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code. ran command: salt
>   '`minion*`' state.apply nettools

Running on Ubuntu Server 18.04 with XFCE desktop, I've tried having the sls in etc/salt/ and in the home directory

```
install_network_packages:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - rsync
      - lftp
      - curl
```

> I receive data failed to compile: `no matching sls found for 'nettools' in env 'base'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt's states (sls files) go in `/srv/salt/` unless you've modified the `file_roots` option in your master config file.

So if you place your file in `/srv/salt/nettools.sls` you should be able to run the following command:

```
salt <minion id> state.apply nettools
```